# Appendices title before list of appendices

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, appendices

My table of contents has the following form:

```
1. Foo ............................. 1
2. Boo ............................. 2
A. something 1 ..................... 3
B. something 2 ..................... 4
```

But I would like it to look the following way:

```
1. Foo ............................. 1
2. Boo ............................. 2
Appendices
A. something 1 ..................... 3
B. something 2 ..................... 4
```

I use `scrbook` if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With KOMA-Script you can use:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendices}
```

**Update:** If you want the Title apendices also print as own page you can use:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}   

\phantomsection                            % hyperref jumps to this point
\chapter*{Appendices}\label{sec:Anhang}    % no entry in toc
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendices} % entry in toc without numbering
```

**Update 2**: To get `Appendices`in the table of contents without pagenumbering use:

```
\addchap*{Appendices}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\usekomafont{chapterentry}{Appendices}}
```

**Update 3**: To be sure that you get no numbering for the page in the table of contents you can use this "brute force":

```
\addchap*{Appendices}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline {chapter}{Appendices}{}{}}
```

Comment: Not only koma ;-) It's a general approach.

Comment: It's probably best to put a `\clear(double)page` before that so that it ands up pointing to the right page.

Comment: i tried this solution and i get a page number at the right side. Is it possible to tell LaTeX not to place a page number on the right side of Appendices?

Comment: I check the two solutions and in both cases i get a page number in my table of contents, what i try to avoid.

Comment: This code gives me a page with "Part X" and "Appendix" but no page number: \appendix \cleardoubleoddpage \part{\appendixname}